# discord.py Timed Mute command not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command(aliases=['tempmute'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def tmute(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, time=None, *, reason=None):
    if not member:
           await ctx.send("You must mention a member to mute!")
    elif not time:
           await ctx.send("You must mention a time!")
    else:
           if not reason:
                  reason="No reason given"

    try:
        seconds = time[:-1] 
        duration = time[-1] 
        if duration == "s":
            seconds = seconds * 1
        elif duration == "m":
            seconds = seconds * 60
        elif duration == "h":
            seconds = seconds * 60 * 60
        elif duration == "d":
            seconds = seconds * 86400
        else:
            await ctx.send("Invalid duration input")
        return
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    await ctx.send("Invalid time input")
    return
    guild = ctx.guild
    Muted = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if not Muted:
        Muted = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")
    for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=False)
    await member.add_roles(Muted, reason=reason)
    muted_embed = discord.Embed(title="Muted a user", description=f"{member.mention} Was muted by {ctx.author.mention} for {reason} to {time}")
    await ctx.send(embed=muted_embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
    await member.remove_roles(Muted)
    unmute_embed = discord.Embed(title="Mute over!", description=f'{ctx.author.mention} muted to {member.mention} for {reason} is over after {time}')
    await ctx.send(embed=unmute_embed)
```

I do not receive any errors, the code works fine till I get to the time manipulation part of the command so !mute @Test 1d testreason the code works fine till I get to the 1d part then just stops working and I have no idea why, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `seconds` variable is a string. Therefore multiplication returns string also. You need to convert `seconds` to `int` like this:

```py
seconds = int(time[:-1])
```

Also note that using `asyncio.sleep` for timed mute commands is a bad practice. You should use any scheduler or write your own as good.

Comment: I'm now getting the error:

```invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'm'```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0iduCFrB This is a source code of time converter class. Define it in your code. Then write `time: TimeConverter`. D.py will convert an argument using a converter class. It’s a very simple and correct way to convert duration.

Comment: `time` variable represents a seconds of user input. For example 1h30s = 3630 seconds.

Comment: Read more about converters in d.py [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=converter#discord.ext.commands.Converter).